# How to print an array to a .txt file in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, file-io, text-files

I am just beginning to learn **Matlab**, so this question might be very basic:

I have a variable

```
a=[2.3 3.422 -6.121 9 4.55]
```

I want the values to be output to a .txt file like this:

```
2.3
3.422
-6.121
9
4.55
```

How can I do this?

```
fid = fopen('c:\\coeffs.txt','w'); //this opens the file
//now how to print 'a' to the file??
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
fid = fopen('c:\\coeffs.txt','wt');  % Note the 'wt' for writing in text mode
fprintf(fid,'%f\n',a);  % The format string is applied to each element of a
fclose(fid);
```

For more info, check out the documentation for [FOPEN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fopen.html) and [FPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html).

Comment: @gnovice yes, it does. Thanks. Do you know some place where I can lookup for some basic stuff like this. Its because I just started with Matlab and I often find myself stuck at such trivial stuff.

Comment: I thought I will need a loop for that. somehow all the values are printed by itself!!

Comment: @eSKay: I added a couple of links for the pertinent functions. In general, MATLAB has very good documentation and examples/tutorials, both with the version and online at The MathWorks website (http://www.mathworks.com). In the command window, the HELP command (http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/help.html) is usually very, well, helpful. ;)

Comment: @gnovice getting incorrect results in input, posted as a separate ques because it required formatting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457177/how-to-read-input-from-a-text-file-in-matlab

Comment: For matrices can be used dlmwrite, for instance if A is matrix then you can save it with in that way: dlmwrite('file.txt',A)

Comment: How do you store an imaginary matrix? This code only saves the real part of the number.

Comment: @eduardosufan: You can use `fprintf(fid, '%f+%fi\n', real(a), imag(a));` or `dlmwrite('outfile.txt', a, 'delimiter', '\t');`.

Comment: @gnovice Im using the first option. Thanks a lot!