# Whats wrong with this [reading input from a text file in Matlab]?

Tags: matlab, file-io, formatting, input

I have a text file (c:\input.txt) which has:

```
2.0 4.0 8.0 16.0 32.0 64.0 128.0 256.0 512.0 1024.0 2048.0 4096.0 8192.0
```

In Matlab, I want to read it as:

```
data = [2.0 4.0 8.0 16.0 32.0 64.0 128.0 256.0 512.0 1024.0 2048.0 4096.0 8192.0]
```

I tried this code:

```
fid=fopen('c:\\input.txt','rb');
data = fread(fid, inf, 'float');
data
```

but I am getting some garbage values:

```
data =

  1.0e-004 *

    0.0000
    0.0015
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0001
    0.0239
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0066
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0016
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0276
    0.0000
    0.3819
    0.0000
    0.0000
```

**Where is the mistake?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**fread** is for reading binary files only!
The equivalent for text files is **[fscanf](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fscanf.html)**, used as follows:

```
fid = fopen('c:\\input.txt','rt');
data = fscanf(fid, '%f', inf)';
fclose(fid);
```

Or in your case, simply use **[load](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/load.shtml)**:

```
data = load('c:\\input.txt', '-ascii');
```

There are many other ways in MATLAB to read text data from files:

- [dlmread](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/dlmread.html)
- [textscan](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html)
- [importdata](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/importdata.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your file is a text file, so you should open it for text read:

```
fid=fopen('c:\\input.txt','rt');
```

Then, for reading, I find TEXTSCAN to be more powerful than FREAD/FSCANF (the differences between them all are summarized [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1600/1602.html?BB=1)

```
data = textscan(f, '%f')
```

returns a cell array.  You can get at the contents with

```
>> data{1}

ans =

       2
       4
       8
      16
      32
      64
     128
     256
     512
    1024
    2048
    4096
    8192
```

TEXTREAD is easier to use than TEXTSCAN, but according to the documentation is now outdated.