# Writing uint32 type of array contents to text file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, uint32

I am trying to read the contents of a 512*512 matrix of class uint32 to a text file. This matrix has 0s and 1s as its contents. The below code keeps returning me this error: 
"Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object."

```
fileID = fopen('my_data.txt','w');
[nrows,ncols] = size(matri_working_now);
for row = 1: nrows
fprintf(fileID,matri_working_now{row,:});
end
```

Any suggestions/ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing

```
fprintf(fileID,matri_working_now{row,:});
```

with

```
fprintf(fileID,matri_working_now(row,:));
```

It seesm like you are trying to access `matri_working_now` as a cell using curly braces `{}`, while you should access it as a regular matrix using parentheses `()`.

Comment: Well i did try this. Thats when i got the uint32 error.

Comment: @KashifNawaz what's the "`uint32` error"?

Comment: the matrix  is of type uint32 and i think im accessi it as a numeric/string

Comment: with normal brackets, I get the error Error using fprintf. Invalid format.

Comment: this seems to work but it takes the data column wise and outputs it to the text file as a single stream and not as an array         fileID = fopen('my_data2vs.txt','wt');
for row = 1:nrows
fprintf(fileID,'%d\n',matri_working_now(row,:));
end
fclose(fileID);

Comment: the significance of 'wt' is explained here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1456924/1060030